# Cropping image using jcrop and java

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jcrop

I am trying to crop the image using JQuery Jcrop plugin with Java Stuff, but I am unable to get the correct result.

Jsp code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#actualImage').Jcrop({
     setSelect: [0, 0, 268, 180],
     addClass: 'custom',
     bgColor: 'yellow',
     bgOpacity: .8,
     //sideHandles: true
     allowResize: false,
     allowSelect: false,
     onSelect: storeCoords
 });
});

function storeCoords(c) {

 jQuery('#X1').val(c.x);
 jQuery('#Y1').val(c.y); 
 jQuery('#X2').val(c.x2);
 jQuery('#Y2').val(c.y2); 
 jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
 jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
}

function cropPicture(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "cropPhoto.htm",
        type: "POST", 
        data :{
            x : $('input#X1').val(),
            y : $('input#Y1').val(),
            x2 : $('input#X2').val(),
            y2 : $('input#Y2').val(), 
            w : $('input#W').val(),
            h : $('input#H').val(),
            imageName : $('input#imageName').val()
        },
        success: function (data) { 
            window.location = 'photo.htm';
         }
}
</script>
```

Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cropPhoto.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String cropPhoto(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session) throws IOException{
         int x1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("x"));
         int y1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("y"));
         int x2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("x2"));
         int y2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("y2"));
         int w=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("w"));
         int h=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("h"));
         System.out.println(x1+" "+y1+" "+x2+" "+y2+" "+w+" "+" "+h);

         String image = request.getParameter("imageName");
         System.out.println("imageName"+image);

         String sourcePath =   request.getRealPath("") + "/FreeTemp/";
         String serverPath = sourcePath + session.getAttribute("uploadFile");
         serverPath = serverPath.replace("\\", "/");
         System.out.println(serverPath);

         BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(serverPath));

         BufferedImage out = bi.getSubimage(x1, y1, w, h);

         ImageIO.write(out,"jpg",new File(sourcePath + image));

         session.setAttribute("croppedImage", image);

         PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
         response.setContentType("text/html");

        return "redirect:/savephoto.htm";
    }
```

I am able to crop the photo, but the result is not correct. For example look at the following images:

[image: Original Image with selection to crop]
[image: cropped image which is incorrect]

Comment: sure the posted var's are correct? you haven't resized the image container?

Comment: yes thanks for your reply.I solved it by using the pasted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got the problem.I need to resize the image.So, i have done using the following code:

```
public static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type){
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();

        return resizedImage;
    }
```

Now i am able to get the cropped image.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is the image cropping: you are not calculating the actual natural height and natural width of the image. You can try this:

```javascript
function showCoords(c) {
  // get image natural height/width for server site crop image.
    var imageheight = document.getElementById('cropbox').naturalHeight;
    var imagewidth = document.getElementById('cropbox').naturalWidth;
    var xper = (c.x * 100 / jQuery('#cropbox').width());
    var yper = (c.y * 100 / jQuery('#cropbox').height());
    var wPer = (c.w * 100 / jQuery('#cropbox').width());
    var hper = (c.h * 100 / jQuery('#cropbox').height());

    var actX = (xper * imagewidth / 100);
    var actY = (yper * imageheight / 100);
    var actW = (wPer * imagewidth / 100);
    var actH = (hper * imageheight / 100);
    jQuery('#x').val(parseInt(actX));
    jQuery('#y').val(parseInt(actY));
    jQuery('#w').val(parseInt(actW));
    jQuery('#h').val(parseInt(actH));

};
```

If you want a complete example see [this link](http://riddhimajava.blogspot.in/2014/06/javajquery-crop-image.html)